# How to get a cell to display no value if another cell is empty?

Tags: worksheet-function

I want to do the following: The answer for `D13` must be `D12-D11`. However, if I don't put a value in `D11`, `D13` must display nothing, even if there is a value in `D12`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

you have to check if the cell is empty. For this you can use the function ISBLANK. So to get what you want you would enter the following in cell D13 `=IF(ISBLANK(D11),"", D12-D11)` which will show an empty string (so nothing) or the difference if there is something in D11. Bear in mind that this does not check against the type of values in D12 and D11 and might fail (if you put a string in any of those cells)

Comment: Thx Zina. I must be doing something wrong. Keeps on showing error message when I OK formula. I am typing your excact formula in D13. Please bear in mind that I am not a pro in excel......

Comment: Strange. I tested it before posting (excel 2013 on windows). Can you try to copy paste it from the answer?

Comment: Yep I did. Silly question...... I inserted the calculation in D13. Is this correct?

Comment: Can I not mail my speadsheet to you?

Comment: Yes. I used the cells you provided to make it easy. What spreadsheet processor are you using? Try to type it in and see what will popup - with that I mean the formula usage.

Comment: I give up Must there be spaces anywhere in the formula?

Comment: I have saved and shared my working example. find it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7eax5kRPs_eUFE2cGg1S1g1ck0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Try replacing the commas (`,`s) with semicolons (`;`s) — which one to use is a regional (i.e., language-based) setting.  But, if your system is set to English, this formula should work.

Comment: Thx you so much Zina. I will try it later. I am now going to get in the mood for New Year All the best for 2016 for you!

Comment: Happy New Year to you too. Hope you will get it fixed :)

Comment: Thx you Scott. I will try asap again

Comment: Other ideas: (1) If your system is set to a language other than English, try translating "IS BLANK" into your local language.  (2) Try `=IF(D11="", "", D12-D11)` or `=IF(D11=""; ""; D12-D11)`, which should be almost equivalent to Zina's answer.

Comment: Thx you very much Scott. I followed your advice wrt changing the commas with semicolons, and it worked!! :-) Now I want to add a Conditional Format also to a cell below, that says that if there is no value in D11, nothing must appear in D14.

Comment: . What I did was to also put a formula in D14, just to say over or under budget. I did that with =IF(D11<=D12;"Within Budget";"Over budget") I basically wants "under Budget" to highlight in red when the value in D13 is LESS than 0.00. But it must only turns to red when the value is less than 0.00.

Comment: In other words, it must draw your attention when you are not within budget. D11 = Actual. D12 = budget and D13 = variance. D14 will then just tells you in red "over budget"  or "under budget". Just one more thing more - if the variance in D13 is then less than 0.00, it must highlight in red.

Comment: . I got it sort of right, but if the budget en actual is the same, D13 turns to red, and it must only turns to red when the difference is less than 0 (cents included) I am from South Arfica by the way.

Comment: if the values in D11 and D12 are calculated, try rounding them in the check formula to the same places after the decimal point - as those are budget values I assume using 2 would be okay). So you would compare the rounded values to each other.